# Marketing cloud setup with email address as Subscriber key - Remove email in tracking url

Tags: marketing-cloud

We have a marketing cloud solution set up to track Link opens and clicks.

Today, each subscriber has the following properties:
`Email address`, `Subscriber key` where Email address is the email of the subscriber, subscriber key is also the email.

The current problem:

```
We want to remove the email address property in the link 
below "emailaddr", but we still want to track Link opens and clicks.
```

Issue:

```
Is it possible to edit the properties for the link? This link is generated 
by exact target somehow.
```

https://xxx.xx/xxx/xxx/xxx-xxx/??j=%%jobid%%&l=%%list_%%&e=%%emailaddr%%&u=%%JobURLID%%&jb=%%_JobSubscriberBatchID%%&utm_source=MarketingCloud&utm_medium=Email&utm_content=newsletter+w36+subscribers&utm_link=https%3a%2f%2fwww.xxx.xx%2fExpress%2fCampaigns%2discount-866%2f&utm_category=%%__AdditionalEmailAttribute1%%

Answer (score 0):

For the auto-generated link for click tracking, there is no way to alter it from an end user standpoint (you could try talking to your rep to see, but I sincerely doubt it.)

I am assuming this is for security purposes, but keep in mind SFMC does its own encryption of this information prior to the send, so all you see is a string of characters in a single query parameter at the end of the link - and not any personal information. The page it then lands on decrypts this, stores it in their system and then redirects to your page.

If you have a different reason/use case for removing the email address, feel free to comment and I will update my answer.

Comment: Thank you for your response. However we have to remove the email address from the url since we have been informed that we are violating some PII-restrictions for Google adwords. They have informed us that we are not allowed to use email addresses in the urls.

Comment: According to google policy (https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/6366371?hl=en) it is only for information passed to google, so all you need to do is make sure not to pass this information into google analytics and you are fine.  Usually this requires a UTM tag, so just remove that tag for email address and any other PII and you will be fine.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old post, but I have two suggestions:

1) Use the SubscriberID, which is generated by the platform, as the value.  You can then run a query to match the SubscriberID to the clickers (if you need that).

2) Use Base64 Encoding (via AMPscript) to change the email value.  Yes, it's not encrypted but it will fool any system that is looking for an Email Address value.

Good Luck!